# JQuery toggle plus/minus button icon and animate image on click

Tags: jquery

I have a div containing list items, a photo, and a plus/minus icon at the bottom of the div.

The list items are absolutely positioned behind the photo. When I click on the plus button I want it to change to minus and animate the photo 29px from the top revealing the list-items behind it. Then I want to click the minus button changing it back to plus and animate the photo back up to the top.

I'm trying to accomplish something very similar to what you see on [Kyanmedia.com](http://blog.kyanmedia.com/archives/2008/12/10/easy_image_rollovers/). Except their images animate down and up on hover. I want my image to animate down then up on click and toggle the plus/minus image. I've tried this but it doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn_switch').click(function () {

        $(this).addClass('on')
        $('.photo').animate({ top: '29px'}, 500);

        }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('on')
        $('.photo').animate({ top: '0px'}, 500);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use "toggle" instead of click():

```
$(document).ready(function() { $('#btn_switch').toggle(
    function () { /*show*/ },
    function () { /*hide*/ }
);});
```

http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if I understand your question properly but I'll try to answer it the best I can. If you want to have an image animate up than down after an onClick event, this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn_switch').click(function () {
    $('.photo').animate({ top: '29px'}, 500);
    $('.photo').animate({ top: '0px'}, 500);
    });
});
```

For the part about toggling a plus and minus image, could you explain that better?

EDIT: I think I understand what you mean. I used this code on my website to open and close a drawer:

```
var oddClick = true;
$("#btn_switch").click(function() {
$(".photo").animate({top: (oddClick) ? "0px" : "29px"},500);
    if(oddClick){
            $("#btn_switch").html("-");
        }
    else{
                $("#btn_switch").html("+");
        }
    oddClick = !(oddClick);
```

EDIT III: Here is the same solution using the .toggle method:

**First, if you have multiple btn_switch and photo instances you should use classes not ids**

```
$("*").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).addClass("Active");
});

$("*").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("Active");
});

$(".btn_switch.Active").toggle(function(){
        $(".photo.Active").animate({top:29}, 500);
        $(".btn_switch.Active").html("-");
        }, 
        function(){
        $(".photo.Active").animate({top:0}, 500);
        $(".btn_switch.Active").html("+");
      });
```

The first part adds the class Active to anything the mouse is hovering over so only an Active btn_switch will toggle anything. This is assuming though that the Plus/Minus button is over the .photo or else the photo wont have an Active class attached to it.

Comment: When the plus button is clicked it turns into a minus button and animates the photo 29px from the top. When the minus button is clicked it reverses the process.

Comment: Hey ricosuave that worked. Thanks man, been trying to figure this out for two days.

Comment: haha i must have switched the numbers or something, glad I could help you solve it super quickly. Did you manage to sort everything out? If so let me know so i can edit my code for others.

Comment: The only thing I switched was the order of the animation. "29px" : "0px".                                                              I also changed $("#btn_switch").html("-"); to $(btn_switch").addClass('on') $('#btn_switch').removeClass('on'); That switches out my plus/minus icon.

Comment: The second solution worked flawlessly as well. Now I have another problem. If you have more than one a page it animates them all at once. How do you animate only the button that is currently being clicked on.

Comment: Haha I now see that valipour's suggestion was all you needed, just to change where you originally had click to toggle. hahah oh well.

Comment: it's because it's basically saying that everything with a id cat_panel will animate when you click at button with the id btn_switch. I'll edit my answer to show you a work around

Comment: Appreciate the attempt but don't think this will work because the button is not over the photo. It's at the bottom of the div.

Comment: you could also try linking the button to the photos using the rel attribute in css. you can finagle a way to tell it to only move a photo with the same number i.e. `rel="1"`.